# how do I display firestore data with React

Tags: reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to render my firestore data to my web app using React.

here is my code

[image]

I can see the document ID when I console.log(posts.id), however I cannot find the content of that document.

Here are the content of a document

[image]

Comment: You'll have to use snapshot.forEach and then call doc.data() on each element. It's on the front page of the docs.

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for getting the data is `.data`, as in:

```
console.log(posts[0].data())
```

To render something for each post might be something like:

```
<p>
{posts.map(doc => {
  const data = doc.data();
  return (
    <div>{data.title}</div>
  )
})}
</p>
```

Personally, unless i need something other than the data from the document, i tend to do my calls to `.data()` before i even put it into react state. That way i don't need to do it on each render. e.g:

```
useEffect(() => {
  database.posts.get().then(snapshot => {
    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  });
});
```